#  Are there simple conditions on a category C which guaranty that Ind(C) is a Grothendieck topos?

Tags: topos-theory, sheaf-theory, ct.category-theory

The category of finite sets is not a Grothendieck topos, but its Ind category
Ind(Finite-Sets) = Sets
is a Grothendieck topos. Similarly, given a pro-finite group G, the Grothendieck topos of discrete G-sets is the Ind of the category of finite G-sets.

**Question: Are there simple conditions on a category C which guaranty that Ind(C) is a Grothendieck topos?**

The examples which interests me is of the following kind: I have an infinite sequence of finite groups $(G_i)$ and a corresponding sequence of quotient groups $G_i \to H_i$. I consider the category of sequences $(X_i)$ of finite sets such that each $X_i$ carries a $G_i$-action which factors through $H_i$ for almost all $i$. Even for extreme cases (i.e. $H_i=G_i$, $H_i=1$, or even $G_i=H_1=1$) I don't know if the corresponding Ind-category is a topos. Another possible variant  is to require a uniform bound on the size of the $X_i$'s.

Comment: I believe every coherent topos is the Ind completion of its subcategory of coherent objects. This covers classifying toposes of profinite groups and other similar examples. 

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Is there a way to identify a category as a category of coherent objects? Is there a good reference on the subject of coherent objects/topoi ? 

Comment: The standard books like Jounstone or Mac Lane Moerdijk discuss coherent toposes and objects. I am not sure if they axiomatize them.  Topos theory is not my specialty. 

Answer (score 8):

In Di Liberti–Ramos González's [Gabriel-Ulmer duality for topoi and its relation with site presentations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09391), they state (Theorem 3.17) that $\mathbf{Ind}(\mathscr C)$ is a Grothendieck topos if and only if $\mathscr C$ is [extensive](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category) and *pro-exact* (Definition 3.14 therein).

They attribute this result to Carboni–Pedicchio–Rosický's [Syntactic characterizations of various classes of locally presentable categories](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404901000160), though it does not appear as an explicit theorem there, so it not such a convenient reference.